# how do i ignore duplicate rows in table when inserting into a different my table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, 1 has ~2100 rows and the other is empty. The filled table has lots of repeated data and i would like to insert rows from the filled table to the empty one but without the duplicated data.

I have tried doing this but this just added every row.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (empID, name, salary)
SELECT t1.EmpID, t1.Name, t1.Salary
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.EmpID NOT IN (SELECT table2.empID FROM table2)
```

I would like to know what's the best way to go about doing this.

Comment: `mysql <> sql-server`. I removed the conflicting tags, please add only the relevant one.

Comment: Please spend a few minutes searching Stack Overflow for your problem.  This has been well-covered already elsewhere on the site.

Comment: How do you want to resolve duplicates, take the `MAX` salary, the `MIN` salary, the `AVG` salary for example, or do your duplicates have everything duplicated?

Comment: Considering the OP had tagged PHPMyAdmin, this suggests MySQL; PHPMyAdmin doesn't work with SQL Server.

Comment: I think "a different my table in sql" should probably read "a different table in mySQL"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` instead, because it will fail if sub-query return `null` value :

```
INSERT INTO table2 (empID, name, salary)
    SELECT t1.EmpID, t1.Name, t1.Salary
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.empID = t1.empID);
```

Comment: Yeah, that won't work, table2 starts off empty, that's the actual problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You mentionned that the target table is empty. If you want to insert non-duplicated records from the source table, you could just use `select distinct`:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (empID, name, salary)
SELECT DISTINCT EmpID, Name, Salary FROM table1
```